# Pass SelectedItem to the ViewModel of the UserControl inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have this really simple MVVM code made with Prism:

- 2 Models (Person, Company - common interface IContact) with 2 ViewModels (Prism) and 2 Views (UserControl)
- 1 ViewModel (collection of interface IContact) with 1 View (ListBox bound to the collection and a ContentControl bound to ListBox's SelectedItem with DataTemplateSelector that returns one of the two UserControls based on the type of the SelectedItem)

**How can I pass the Model object (either Person or Company) from the ListBox's SelectedItem (IContact) to one of the two ViewModels (either PersonViewModel or CompanyViewModel) that match the View returned by the DataTemplateSelector (either PersonView or CompanyView)?**

Thank you!

---

There is a lot of code, but it is really simple:

I have these Model classes:

```
public interface IContact
{
    string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IContact
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IContact
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I have these ViewModel classes:

```
public class ContactViewModel : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<IContact> _contacts = new ObservableCollection<IContact>();
    public ObservableCollection<IContact> Contacts
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _contacts, value); }
    }
}

public class PersonViewModel : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
{
    private Person _person; // I want to set this from the ListBox's SelectedItem
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _person, value); }
    }
}

public class CompanyViewModel : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
{
    private Company _company; // I want to set this from the ListBox's SelectedItem
    public Company Company
    {
        get { return _company; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _company, value); }
    }
}
```

I have these View classes:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContactView"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate">
            <local:PersonView>
                // How can I pass the SelectedItem to the ViewModel of this UserControl?
            </local:PersonView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CompanyDataTemplate">
            <local:CompanyView>
                // How can I pass the SelectedItem to the ViewModel of this UserControl?
            </local:CompanyView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <dataTemplateSelectors:contactDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
              PersonDataTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}" 
              CompanyDataTemplate="{StaticResource CompanyDataTemplate}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        // RowDefinitions here
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" x:Name="myListBox">
            // ItemTemplate here
        </ListBox>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" 
            Content="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" 
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Person:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PersonView"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Address}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Company:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CompanyView"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.Address}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this:

```
public class ContactDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate PersonDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CompanyDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Person)
        {
            return PersonDataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is Company)
        {
            return CompanyDataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add a property to the ContactViewModel  if you wan to keep track of the selected item in the ListBox?

Comment: @mm8 The code is very simplified. My goal is not to track the selected item in the `ContactViewModel` class - that would be a very simple binding to a property. My goal is to pass the selected item from the `ContactViewModel` to either `PersonViewModel` or `CompanyViewModel` trough the `ContentControl` via `DataTemplateSelector` that returns either `PersonView` or `CompanyView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use view first (a.k.a. `ViewModelLocator`) here. Go view model first.

Long version:

Make `Contacts` (the item source of the list box) contain view models. Then directly bind `SelectedItem` to the content control.

The listbox uses one data template to show the contacts, the content control uses another. You don't even need the selector, just set `DataType` on your data templates.

When you already have the item at hand that you want to show (i.e. its view model), just bind and show that one. If you want to navigate to a screen in your app (e.g. login dialog), use the `ViewModelLocator`. It basically is a workaround for *not* having the view model ready.

Comment: The code in the question is very simplified. The reason why `Contacts` contains Models and not ViewModels is because it comes from the `ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local` in `DbSet<TEntity>` in `DbContext` in `Entity Framework` - which of course shouldn't contain ViewModels. The only work-around would be to copy the collection.

Comment: Not only copy, you have to map the collection. Not funny, but inevitable, most of the time, _if_ you want to change it from the database _and_ the gui. But you shouldn't expose the database classes to the view anyway, so you have to at least create a list of view models from the list of models.

Comment: Agreed with @Haukinger as what would happen if you wanted extra information added to the objects to be viewed. You need to map to a new object, i.e. ViewModel, that may at first look like a copy and additional work but it will allow you're objects to differ in the longer term.

Comment: While your answer seems obvious once you have stated it, I have been thinking of a good way to do this for the whole day. Just been too used to mapping models to the source of CollectionView, like the Xamarin examples show.

Comment: @Jinjinov As you have marked this answer, can you please help me how did you achieve this ? I've exact same problem , but I couldn't figure out a way to make this work.

Comment: @SagarPanwala I have posted my solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## All credit goes to Haukinger!

This answer is just because Sagar Panwala asked how I did it...

---

In the end I did not do it exactly the way I imagined at first.

I did it a little bit different:

The `BindableBase` ViewModel:

```
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, PositioningModuleSetting>>? SelectedSettings;
```

The `PositioningModuleSetting` class:

```
public class PositioningModuleSetting
{
    public string Section { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public dynamic value = null!;
    public string description = string.Empty;
    public PositioningModuleRestart restart;

    public Action<PositioningModuleSetting>? OnSettingChanged { get; set; }

    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; OnSettingChanged?.Invoke(this); }
    }

    public double DoubleValue
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; OnSettingChanged?.Invoke(this); }
    }

    public long LongValue
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; OnSettingChanged?.Invoke(this); }
    }

    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; OnSettingChanged?.Invoke(this); }
    }

    public object ObjectValue
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; OnSettingChanged?.Invoke(this); }
    }

    public void Initialize(string section, string name, Action<PositioningModuleSetting> onSettingChanged)
    {
        Section = section;
        Name = name;
        OnSettingChanged = onSettingChanged;
    }
}
```

The `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
public class SettingsDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate? DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate? BoolDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate? DoubleDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate? LongDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate? StringDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate? SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is KeyValuePair<string, PositioningModuleSetting> pair)
        {
            return pair.Value.value switch
            {
                bool _ => BoolDataTemplate,
                double _ => DoubleDataTemplate,
                long _ => LongDataTemplate,
                string _ => StringDataTemplate,
                _ => DefaultDataTemplate
            };
        }

        return DefaultDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

The `UserControl` View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock MinWidth="180" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="240" Text="{Binding Path=Value.ObjectValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BoolDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock MinWidth="180" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value.BoolValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DoubleDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock MinWidth="180" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="240" Text="{Binding Path=Value.DoubleValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LongDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock MinWidth="180" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="240" Text="{Binding Path=Value.LongValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock MinWidth="180" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="240" Text="{Binding Path=Value.StringValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallestFontSize}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <dataTemplateSelectors:SettingsDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          BoolDataTemplate="{StaticResource BoolDataTemplate}" 
          DoubleDataTemplate="{StaticResource DoubleDataTemplate}" 
          LongDataTemplate="{StaticResource LongDataTemplate}" 
          StringDataTemplate="{StaticResource StringDataTemplate}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedSettings}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTextBlock}" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```